# Do imported modules have the same working directory as the file being executed?

Tags: python, working-directory

Suppose I have a file called `myfile.py` in `/Users/joe/Documents`:

```
import mymodule

mymodule.foobar()
```

Now let's say that I need to fetch the current working directory of `myfile.py` in `mymodule` (which is in another location). Do they both have the same working directory because I am importing `mymodule` into `myfile`, or does `mymodule` have it's working directory as the directory of where it was installed

Comment: The working directory of a Python script (or any other program) is initially inherited from the shell that launched the script, the directory where the script (or any modules it imports) is irrelevant. Of course, it's _possible_ for a module to change the current working directory when it's imported, but a properly written module shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are importing the module, they both have the same working directory, meaning that completing operations with `os` will be successful (or whatever other purpose you are using the current working directory for).